# Castle Active Record - specify assemblies to load before Initialize

Tags: c#, castle-activerecord

The framework we're planning is divided into multiple modules responsible for single units of work and they shouldn't know about each other.

However, each module could have it's own domain objects (I know the castle documentation prefers one assembly).

I've know that you can add assemblies after Initialize by using:

```
ActiveRecordStarter.RegisterAssemblies(typeof(SomeModuleSpecificClass).Assembly);
```

However I would like each module to register itself if required and only much later actually initialize castle.

At the moment it's not quite as simple as strarting ActiveRecord first.

Answer (score 0):

we have the same and I never saw anything about only one assembly with busines objects.
I simply analyzed all assemblies in the startup-directory and loaded/initalized all possible AcitveRecord-types from them. You could also define a list of strings to identify and load the assemblies in the settings of your main/starup-assembly (*.exe) or a list of directory that should be scanned. Or all of that.

Greetings
Juy Juka